# Regex for dates that matches for every stage of valid date entry

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I'm trying to put together a regex that matches on *any* part of a valid date as long as the part starts from the front. A valid date is defined as DD/MM/YYYY with 1900 <= YYYY < 2100. I'm not fussed with leap years, days per months different depending on month, etc.

The purpose is to provide validation feedback to users as they type but only when they're on the wrong track. I believes this improves the user experience.

So, for example:

```
'1' matches (as e.g. 12/12/1999 is a valid date)
'4' does not match
'04' matches
'12/12/' matches
```

This is where I got:

```
^(([0123]\d?)|([0123]\d\/[01]?)|([0123]\d\/[01]\d\/?)|([0123]\d\/[01]\d\/(1|2|19\d{0,2}|20\d{0,2})))$
```

Any easier way to do this with regex?

Comment: Any reason you're not using a date picker of some kind?

Comment: @robert: I think date pickers work very well for dates close the current date but not so well for dates that are far off

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes: yes, but there will be another check done which is based on the javascript date function and can only be performed once the input is complete. If 30/02 etc can be handled by the regex then that would be great, but I would imagine that would make it significantly more complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. The basic approach is, if the input has parts A, B, and C, then write:

```
/^A(B(C)?)?$/
```

and so on, for any number of segments. This makes the entire part starting with B optional, so A by itself will match. It makes the C optional, so AB will match. And of course ABC will match.

The catch here is handling the century, which requires a bit of special handling. Altogether, the solution looks something like

```
/^[0-3](\d(\/([01](\d(\/((1(9(\d(\d)?)?)|((2(0(\d(\d)?)?)?))?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?$/
```

Comment: Cool, that helped... I think this does the trick but need further testing: `/^([0123](\d(\/([01](\d(\/(1|2|19\d{0,2}|20\d{0,2})?)?)?)?)?)?)?$/`