# How can I create a "progressively matching" regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex that matches a string as the user types it. It's a bit hard to explain, so let me show what I mean:

It should match this string:

`"XXXX units"`, where XXXX is any number.

But it should also match any substring from the beginning of that string, so:

```
"123"
"123 u"
"123 uni"
```

should also match.

But of course, this should not match:

```
"123 xx"
```

It seems so simple, but I can't quite figure it out. This is the closest I've got:

```
^\d+ ?u?n?i?t?s?
```

...but that unfortunately also matches strings like "123us".

Can anyone help? It's javascript, so I may be a bit limited by missing look behind/ahead features...

Comment: @CodeiSir - that also matches things like "123 us", which it shouldn't... :)

Comment: ^\d+ (u(n(i(t(s)?)?)?)?)?$

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33213891/regex-for-dates-that-matches-for-every-stage-of-valid-date-entry/33215086#33215086.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add some `()`:

```
/^\d+( (u(n(i(t(s)?)?)?)?)?)?$/
```

Testing:

```
/^\d+( (u(n(i(t(s)?)?)?)?)?)?$/.test("123 units")  -> true
/^\d+( (u(n(i(t(s)?)?)?)?)?)?$/.test("123 un")     -> true
/^\d+( (u(n(i(t(s)?)?)?)?)?)?$/.test("123 ui")     -> false
/^\d+( (u(n(i(t(s)?)?)?)?)?)?$/.test("12")         -> true
/^\d+( (u(n(i(t(s)?)?)?)?)?)?$/.test("123 xx")     -> false
```

Comment: Yeah it does, doesn't it ;-) You could also split on space, match the first part with `\d+` and the last part with `"units".indexOf(...)==0`.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look great, but it gets the job done...

```
^(\d+( (u(n(i(t(s)?)?)?)?)?)?)?$
```

Comment: You're missing the `$` at the end - it will also match `123 xx`.

Comment: Well spotted! This one is trickier than it seemed :) Mindless consistency seems to be key. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Demo here: https://regex101.com/r/uC7pX1/6

```
/^\d+( (u(n(i(t(s)?)?)?)?)?)?$/
```

Comment: Also matches "123units" without the space. Does not match the empty string (which certainly is a valid prefix).