# Regex to validate optional parts of a bigger format

Tags: javascript, regex

The general format is:

```
YYYY/MM/DD/INFO
```

- Only the separators `/` are mandatory.
- Each part is optional.
- `YYYY` - exactly 4 numbers.
- `MM` - exactly 2 numbers.
- `DD` - exactly 2 numbers.
- `INFO` - any sequence of letters, spaces or hyphens.

So these are valid strings:

```
2020/06/25/XYZConf
2020///XYZConf
2020//25/XYZConf
2020/06//XYZConf
//25/XYZConf
///
```

I'm really struggling to come up with a regex that validates optional parts *while* maintaining the integrity of the string as a whole.

**How would you write this regular expression?**

*PS: This needs to be a regular expression as it will be part of a third-party lexer that doesn't accept anything else.*

Relevant posts:

- [Regex to validate comma-separated numbers with optional fractional parts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33368539/1244884)
- [Regex for dates that matches for every stage of valid date entry](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33213891/1244884)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
^(?:\d{4})?\/(?:(?:\d\d)?\/){2}(?:[A-Za-z\s-]+)?$
```

See the [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sh0Q6c/1)

I believe that you are looking for optional (non)capturing groups. The pattern above matches:

- `^` - Start string ancor.
- `(?:` - Open 1st non-capturing group.

  - `\d{4}` - Match 4 digits.
  - `)?` - Close 1st non-capturing group and make it optional.
- `\/` - Match a forward slash.
- `(?:` - Open 2nd non-capturing group.

  - `(?:` - Open 3rd non-capturing group.

    - `\d\d` - Match two digits.
    - `)?` - Close 3rd non-capturing group and make it optional.
  - `\/` - Match a forward slash.
  - `){2}` - Close 2nd non-capturing group and make it match twice.
- `(?:` - Open 4th non-capturing group.
- `[A-Za-z\s-]+` - Match upper- and lowercase letters, a space and hyphen at least one time (in any sequence as per your OP).
- `)?` - Close 4th non-capturing group and make it optional.
- `$` - End string ancor.

Comment: I appreciate you took the time to explain everything bits by bits. Great answer!